# Set XML Node name for internal list

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I created this class as a way to control the root node element. this is working

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MyNode")]
public class Foo : List<Bar>{}
```

Bar looks like this

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MyNextNode")]
public class Bar
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CodeType { get; set; }
}
```

the output looks like this

```
<MyNode>
    <Bar>
    </Bar>
</MyNode>
```

the desired output is

```
<MyNode>
    <MyNextNode>
    </MyNextNode>
</MyNode>
```

any suggestions on how to accomplish this without changing the class name for Bar to MyNextNode (changing the class name gets the desired results)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `XmlRoot` on your `Bar` class you should use [`XmlTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "MyNextNode")]
public class Bar
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CodeType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did it this way `[XmlType("Instrument")]` but you are absolutely right! thank you sir